# make sub sub menu with ul li tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying and obtain this, (that is something like: sub-menu and sub-sub-menu):

css

```
        ul li {
            width: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #090;
        }


        #here {
            float: left;
        }

        #sub_list {
            float: left
        }
```

and html

```
     <ul>
        <li>aaa</li>
        <li id="here">bbb</li>
        <ul id="sub_list">
            <li>bbb_1</li>
            <li>bbb_2</li>
            <li>bbb_3</li>
        </ul>
        <li>ccc</li>
     </ul>
```

demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/Muj3d/15/

tell please, how obtain that result, what is seen on image

http://www.imagehosting.cz/?v=sur.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A `UL` between who `LI`s is invalid HTML. Move your sub-menu into the `LI`, apply `position:relative` to the LI and use `position:absolute` to position the sub-menu (UL UL).